# Count and print char frequency in text using streams, no maps, no key-value pairs

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I'm trying to count and print the frequency of all characters in a text.
I want to do this using an `Array` or `ArrayList` and no maps with key-value pairs.

The code below gives the preferred result.
I want to get rid of the `for` loop of `main` 
And do all the work in method `countLetters()`.

To be clear, I wish to do this in a functional way not using any for loops or if statements.
Can this be done? And if so, how?

```
public class LetterCounter4 {
```

`public static void main(String[] a) {

    System.out.print("Input text > ");

    int[] res = countLetters();

    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if(res[i] != 0){
            System.out.println((char) ('a' + i) + " appears "
                + res[i] + ((res[i] == 1 ? " time" : " times")));
        }
    }
}

private static int[] countLetters() {


    return Arrays.stream(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().toLowerCase()
            .split(""))
            .map(s -> s.charAt(0))
            .filter(Character::isLetter)
            .collect(Collector.of(
                    () -> new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(26, 0)),
                    (li, el) -> {
                        Integer oInt = li.get(el - 'a');
                        li.set(el - 'a', ++oInt);
                    },
                    (result1, result2) -> {
                        for (int i = 0; i < result1.size(); i++) {
                            Integer temp = result1.get(i);
                            result1.set(i, temp + result2.get(i));
                        }
                        return result1;
                    }))
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
            .toArray();    
    }
}`

Comment: Then it would only print the values of the list, no? But I would be unable to link every value to the corresponding character. Except if I could know what index of the list I'm printing in each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward way is to use `.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.counting())`.  The code would be simpler and won't blow up when somebody enters À or some other letter outside [a-zA-Z] range.  But that would create a `Map`, which you say you don't want.

If you specifically wish to stick with arrays and lists, here's a way to do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

    int[] counts = countLetters(input);

    IntStream.range(0, counts.length)
            .filter(i -> counts[i] > 0)
            .forEachOrdered(i -> System.out.printf("%c appears %s %s%n", 
                    'a' + i, 
                    counts[i], 
                    counts[i] > 1 ? "times" : "time"
            ));
}

public static int[] countLetters(String s) {
    return s.chars() // this is better than stream(split(""))
            .filter(Character::isLetter)  // WRONG to assume that all letters are [a-zA-Z]
            .map(chr -> Character.toLowerCase(chr) - 'a')
            .collect(
                    () -> new int[26], 
                    (ary, i) -> ary[i]++, 
                    (a,b) -> Arrays.setAll(a, i -> a[i] + b[i])
            );
}
```

Comment: This does indeed what I was looking for. The combiner for collect can be subsituted by (a, b) -> { for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { a[i] += b[i]; } But in your case, you pass i -> a[i] += b[i] as body for the method in the functional interface used by setAll. How come you only have to pass int i as parameter and not i, a, b? I was expecting a functional interface asking for 3 parameters. In order to know the arrays it has to work with.

Comment: @xtra sorry, that was a typo (although the code still works).  It should read `i -> a[i] + b[i]`.  `i` is passed explicitly.  `a` and `b` are *captured* from the enclosing scope.

Comment: When you say “WRONG to assume that all letters are [a-zA-Z]” you should not make the same mistake by collecting into a fixed-size array of length `26`… Either, filter for `[a-zA-Z]` or collect into something supporting other characters. Returning an array would not be the best choice when supporting all unicode letters…

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample code Hope this is what you are asking

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class LetterCounter4 {

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        System.out.print("Input text > ");   
        countLetters();
    }

    private static void countLetters() {
        try {
            Arrays.stream(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().toLowerCase().split(""))
                 .flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split("\\s+")))
                 .map(String::toLowerCase)
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(word -> word, word -> 1, Integer::sum))
                 .entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .sorted((a, b) -> a.getValue() == b.getValue() ? a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey()) : b.getValue() - a.getValue())
                 .forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This would indeed do what I'm looking for. But I don't want to use for loops and if statements. Only functional programming.

Comment: If you want "space" (" ") also to be counted means remove "\\s+" from split function